# Generic linked list code C

Tags: c, generics

I have created this code: implementation of a linked list in C.

To test it I created a label struct which contains a `string` and `int` variables.

The code is commented well and tested before uploaded to here.

I would like to hear your opinion about it, also I'm not that sure the `free` and `malloc` are working well (I used [DrMemory](http://drmemory.org/) and it showed no mistakes but memory is a "leaky" thing (lol)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*label */
/*The label is managed by lnode, which contains the address-string(8-bits)
  and the label-name. */
  typedef struct label{
            int   address;             /* The address number.                      */
            char* name;                /* The name of the label.                   */
  }label;

/*Label implementation*/
/*Create label object*/
  label* createLabel(int address, char* name)
  {
      int len;
      label* newlabel;
      if(NULL == name){
         return NULL;
      }
      len = strlen(name)+1;
      newlabel = (label*)malloc(sizeof(label));
      if(NULL == (newlabel->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len))){
        return NULL;
      }
    /*copy name to new-label name*/
      strcpy(newlabel->name, name);
    /*set address in newlabel*/
      newlabel->address = address;
      return(newlabel);
  }
/*delete label object*/
  void deleteLabel(void* ob ){
       label *lbl;
       if(NULL == ob){
          return;
       }
       lbl = (label*)ob;
     /*delete the name*/
       free(lbl->name);
     /*delete the Label object*/
       free(lbl);
  }

/*Print Label-objects --> for Testing*/
/*Allocate a string and fill with label data*/
  void printLabel(void* ob){
       label* obl= (label*)ob;
       printf("%s%d,  label: %-10s, ","address: ",obl->address,obl->name);
  }






/*gnode*/
/*generic-node struct to be used in a generic list*/
  struct gnode{
       void *value;        /*pointer to generic-node */
       struct gnode* next; /*pointer to next node    */
  }typedef gnode;


/*createGnode*/
/*create a gnode to be added to a generic-list*/
  gnode* createGnode( void* value, gnode* next){
      gnode* newnode=NULL;
      if(NULL == value){
         return NULL;
      }
      if (NULL == (newnode = (gnode*)malloc(sizeof(gnode)))) {
        return NULL;
      }
    /*add the value*/
      newnode->value = value;
    /*set next value to be NULL --> All added gnode are
      added at the end of the list and become the last node */
      newnode->next = next;
      return(newnode);
  }



/*freeGnode*/
/*free the allocated gnode, using a function to delete the pointed value  */
  void freeGnode(gnode* nodetodelete,  void (*deletefunc)( void*)){
     if(NULL == nodetodelete){
        return;
     }
   /*delete the value, pointed by void* value */
     deletefunc(nodetodelete->value);
   /*free the allocated gnode*/
     free(nodetodelete);
  }


/*insertGnode --> insert gnode to list*/
  int insertGnode(gnode** glist, gnode* newnode)
  {
      gnode* curr; /*pointer to current node in list*/
      if(NULL == newnode){
         return -1; /*no item to insert*/
      }
    /*Empty list*/
      else if(NULL == *glist){
              *glist = newnode;
              return 1;
      }
    /*add newnode in last place in list*/
    /*Get to last node*/
      for( curr = *glist; curr->next != NULL; curr = curr->next);
    /*Add the newnode as last node*/
      curr->next = newnode;
    /*return Success*/
      return 1;
  }


/*deleteGenericList*/
/*Parse each generic-node and delete */
  void deleteGenericList(gnode* glist, void (*deleteValue)(void*))
  {
     gnode* curr=NULL;
     gnode* next;
     if(NULL == glist){
        return;
     }
   /*Delete each generic-node*/
     for(curr = glist; curr != NULL; ){
         next = curr->next;
         deleteValue(curr->value); /*free the value objext     */
         free(curr);               /*free current generic-node */
         curr = next;
     }
   /*Set glist to point at NULL*/
     glist = NULL;
  }/*End deleteGenericList*/


/*writeGlist --> write Gnode to an open-file*/
  void writeGenericList(FILE* fp, gnode* glist, void (*writeValue)(FILE*, void*))
  {
      gnode* curr=NULL; /*curr node in the generic-list*/
    /*check that all arguments are present*/
      if( (NULL == fp)||(NULL==glist)||(NULL==writeValue) ){
           return;
      }
    /*use the writeValue function to write the gnode into the file*/
      for(curr = glist; curr != NULL; curr=curr->next){
          writeValue(fp, curr->value);
      }
  }/*End writeGenericList*/


/*For testing...*/
  void printGlist(gnode* glist, void (*printValue)(void*)){
      gnode *curr;
      if(NULL == glist){
         return;
      }
      for (curr = glist; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
           printValue(curr->value);
      }
  }


  void printGlistOLD(gnode* glist, void (*printValue)(void*)){
      gnode *curr;
      if(NULL == glist){
         return;
      }
      printf("%-20s\n", "GenericList: top-To-Bottom");
      for (curr = glist; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
           printValue(curr->value);
      }
  }

  int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  {
    printf("start\n");
    label *label1 = createLabel(100,"hello world");
    label *label2 = createLabel(101,"a");
    label *label3 = createLabel(102,"b");
    label *label4 = createLabel(100,"c");
    label *label5 = createLabel(103,"d");
    label *label6 = createLabel(102,"e");


    gnode* g1 = createGnode(label1,NULL);
    gnode* g2 = createGnode(label2,NULL);
    gnode* g3 = createGnode(label3,NULL);
    gnode* g4 = createGnode(label4,NULL);
    gnode* g6 = createGnode(label6,NULL);
    gnode* g5 = createGnode(label5,g6);

    printf("%d\n",insertGnode(&g1,g2));
    printf("%d\n",insertGnode(&g1,g3));
    printf("%d\n",insertGnode(&g1,g4));
    printf("%d\n",insertGnode(&g1,g5));

    printGlistOLD(g1,printLabel);

    deleteGenericList(g1,deleteLabel);
    return 0;
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's a memory leak in your code: if allocation of a new label succeeds but allocation for its name fails, you `return NULL` and do not `free()` the label structure.

Answer (score 1):

- As I mentioned in the previous review, don't duplicate code in comments. We understand the purpose of `strcpy(newlabel->name, name);` very well.
- As I mentioned in the previous review, **do not cast malloc**.
- `insertGnode` doesn't *insert into*, but rather *appends to* a list. Consider renaming.

  You don't seem to worry of the order of the nodes in the list. Consider *prepending* the new node, as in

  ```
  int add_gnode(gnode** glist, gnode* newnode)
  {
      if (newnode == NULL) {
          return -1;
      }
      newnode->next = *glist;
      *glist = newnode;
      return 1;
  }
  ```

  This approach has two benefits:

  - it doesn't traverse an entire list just to find the tail, and
  - it doesn't special case an empty list.
- `printGlist` shall call `writeGenericList` with proper arguments.
- You seem to strive toward OOP approach. Consider making a `genericList` structure having `deletefunc`, `writeValue`, etc as members.

Answer (score 1):

- you consistently cast `void *` when you should not in C language:

  ```
  newlabel = (label*)malloc(sizeof(label));
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  newlabel = malloc(sizeof(label));
  ```

  and

  ```
  void printLabel(void* ob) {
      label* obl = (label*)ob;
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  void printLabel(void* ob) {
      label* obl = ob;
  ```
- you have a potential memory leak in `create_label`:

  ```
  newlabel = malloc(sizeof(label)); // don't cast malloc
  if (NULL == (newlabel->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*len))) {
      return NULL;                  // leak previously allocated label
  }
  ```
- names are inconsistent for gnode management: `createGnode` inserts node at first position when comment says last, and `insertGnode` adds it at last position
- `freeGnode` unconditionnaly frees a node and its content, possibly breaking any link if you remove a node in a list => show at least be explicit in a comment that you cannot remove a node from a list
- in `deleteGenericList(gnode* glist, void(*deleteValue)(void*))`, the last instruction (`glist = NULL;`) is a no-op because is only set the local value in the function that will go out of scope at next line
- you should considere to add a function to remove a node from a list